# How can we Generate CSV and JTL Report at same time from command line?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Can we generate CSV and .JTL Report at same time as i need CSV report for generating  Dashboard Report and .JTL for generating  Perform Metrics collector image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `either jtl or csv` to generate the `Dashboard report` and `Perform Metrics collector graphs any other graphs)`. No need of capturing in separate formats.

I don't think so there is a way to generate both (specifying -l two times will give an error saying Duplicate options. And In non-gui mode, listeners can't be accessed.

You can refer the following link to capture the results in non-gui mode:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-2-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode